# JVM crashes when loading a native library

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface

I'm working on a CD burner using java, where ( using JNI ) i must load some native libraries (DLL). Well, i know that to load a native library using "System.loadLibrary(libName)", the library must be set to one of the "java.library.path" paths, however if using "System.load(libPath)" there is no need for that.

So, i used to load all my native libraries using "System.load(`libPath`)" and that worked for all of them except a single one `"BurnerCaller.dll"` that causes a `JVM` crash with the error message below.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (0xe0434352), pid=2280, tid=0x00000000000013a8
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_92-b14) (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.92-b14 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0xaa7d]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Program Files\Java\MainWorkspace\NewAman\hs_err_pid2280.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jju1d536mi2ek67/hs_err_pid7096.log?dl=0) is the detailed result error.

The weird thing is that **if and only if** i put this library to the "**bin**" directory of the currently running `JRE` or `JDK` (that my application is using to run) it works like a charm.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really have multiple native libraries *containing JNI code*? Normally you would only have one, and it would have DLL references out to any other native stuff it used.

Comment: no its only a unique library that  contains the _JNI Code_

Comment: So that's the only library you need to load.

Comment: @Mdev, Please attach hs_err_pid2280.log to your question, it will help to find a problem

Comment: hello SerCe, i had edited my post so please find the dropbox-link for the hs_err file in the post above.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try other JDK (Oracle JDK, Open JDK, versions 6,7,8). make sure dll bitness (32 vs 64) match JDK bitness
2. Debug native code

It looks like pure native problem and you should use native tools.

If you have source code of BurnerCaller.dll you can attach(Visual Studio, WinDbg)\debug\fix it. At least you will see the stacktrace of native crash. 
If you don't have the souce - just put it in java **bin** directory, the easiest way.

When system loader loads a library, it calls DllMain for this library, looks like the bug is somewhere around it.

Comment: thank a lot for your answer, i have the code of the library and i will try to debug it right now. I hope that it works!!